# AbpSession.UserId return null after login

Tags: asp.net-core, angular5, asp.net-core-2.0, aspnetboilerplate

I used `Asp.Net Zero` (`Asp.Net Boilerplate` framework) in a project.
There is a problem on Chrome (some computers) and Internet Explorer (all computers) :

When authenticating with login information, the response returns with success. 
But when redirect from login page to the app, `auth-guard.service` check current login information. This time, the application tries to get `UserId` from `AbpSession` and returns null, also page redirect to the login page again, although login was succeed.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Are you use its related to your application? Sounds to me more like an issue on these computers that may be set not to accept any cookies. Without cookies authentication doesn't works. Did you check that the cookies are set correctly?

Comment: @Tseng, I'll check it where a problem occurs. For me, a problem occurs only IE and cookies is allowed.

Comment: @vaqifrv is this issue resolved, I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check your browsers whether they accept cookies.
When you login, you have to see the at least **Abp.AuthToken** and **enc_auth_token** cookies. You can use [EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg) editor to see your current cookies easily.

[image: Cookies]

Comment: Thank you, I used this extension and cookies in pictures is exist also my Chrome. But a problem occurs in some clients, I must check it on their's PC. For me, a problem occurs on the Internet Explorer.
I used `abp.auth.setToken(authToken, expireDate);` method for setting token and then call `var token = abp.auth.getToken();` for testing setted value. I saw that the value set successfully. But when I put a breakpoint in the backend, `AbpSession.UserId` is null.

Comment: actually token cookie and authentication cookie is different. token is kinda security key but authentication cookie specifies the user. so you are looking in the wrong place. When you write `abp.session.userId` on the client-side (JavaScript) you have to be getting a user id. Beside, do you get any JavaScript console errors? Another question is Swagger working fine?

Comment: And please try to update to the latest ABP. Maybe you encountered an error that has been previously fixed.

Comment: I also have the same issue. did u resolve this?. for me this issue happens when code running in IIS virtual directory.

Comment: @Leo Im also facing the same issue when deployed to IIS, code works fine on my local. Did you resolve this issue?